# List matches in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to correlate two data sets. both data sets have the same ID in column A, but different results in the next column as they are measured on different machines.

They are organised so that column A has all the ID numbers, then the measurement results are next to them in columns B,C,D,E etc.

I would like to have a third sheet in the workbook which lists all of the matches, I can use XLOOKUP to find matches fine, but i need the list to only show matches, using any LOOKUP (V or X) it will list the matches but also show 0 or #NA for non matches.

Is there a way where i can get it to list all the matches but skip any that it couldn't find a match for

Comment: You need `FILTER()` function. Or `XLOOKUP()` has option to set `if not found`. Set `""` to that option.

Comment: Setting the "if not found" to "" leaves me with blanks, which is ok, but i want it to skip passed those and try to list only matches with no blanks, is that possible?

Comment: Then `FILTER()` is appropriate for you, I assume. Post few sample data and desired output then we can suggest better formula.

Comment: ok, so i have it working for me using the filter function, but i have it on a seperate sheet, it works like this for now, i will work on a way to get it to find matches and filter out blanks all in one, if thats possible but thanks for your help!

Comment: What you are describing does sound like something the `FILTER()` function alone can do. For more specific answers you should share screenshots of sample data and your desired outcome